# BSD sed ignores the leading spaces in the text for a\ command

Tags: shell, sed, posix, whitespace

Leading spaces are preserved in `echo` command. Take this script for example:

```
echo 'abc
    def'
```

Output:

```
$ sh foo.sh 
abc
    def
```

But leading space in `sed` text for `a\` command is not preserved with the BSD `sed` that comes with `macOS`. Take this script:

```
echo abc | sed '/abc/a\
    def
'
```

Output with BSD `sed` on macOS:

```
$ sh foo.sh 
abc
def
```

Output with GNU `sed` on Linux:

```
$ sh foo.sh
abc
    def
```

I am able to resolve this issue on macOS and preserve the leading spaces like this:

```
echo abc | sed '/abc/a\
\ \ \ \ def
'
```

Output:

```
$ sh foo.sh 
abc
    def
```

Where is the behavior of ignoring leading spaces in the text for `a\` command specified in [POSIX documentation of `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)?

I could not find anything in the documentation that says this behavior of ignoring leading spaces in the text for `a\` is is correct. Can you see anything in the documentation that says this behavior is correct?

Comment: It looks as though you were right.

Comment: The problem with the POSIX `sed` specification is precisely that it does not specify this, or a number of other corner cases.

Comment: The macOS man page for `sed` mostly quotes (or closely paraphrases) the POSIX standard on this.  It doesn't say anything about leading white space being significant or insignificant in a _`text`_ item.  I'm not sure what the pre-POSIX precedents are; ISTR that white space at the beginning of lines was mostly ignored, and macOS may be continuing that tradition.

Comment: sed is best for `s/old/new/`, **that is all**. For anything else you shouldn't be using sed so what various flavors of it do or don't do on various OSes doesn't matter. In this case use `awk '{print} /abc/{print "    def"}'` instead and it'll work robustly, portably, clearly, efficiently, etc. using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you were right. To the extent of the specific observation you have made, the behavior of your `sed` would be nonconforming.

Indeed, POSIX (as you have linked it) says:

> Editing commands other than `{...}`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `i`, `r`, `t`, `w`, `:`, and `#` can be followed by a <semicolon>, optional <blank> characters, and another editing command. However, when an `s` editing command is used with the *w* flag, following it with another command in this manner produces undefined results.

This seems to be as close as POSIX comes to addressing the question, and—by excepting the `a` command from the stipulation—it seems to be admitting that which was already implied. It seems to be admitting that blanks are significant for `a`.

My answer is not wholly conclusive, of course, but you would seem to have the weight of the evidence on your side.